# Analysis techniques for two continuous independent variables: Sales and Commodity Prices

Tags: correlation

I have a hypothesis that the transactional volume (sales per time period) of the business where I work is related to outside economic indicators/commodity prices.

Example: When Crude Oil prices go down, the activity of my business goes up.  In my business, that is probably a true statement with Crude Oil, but of course, that needs proving!

Additionally, Crude Oil is not the only economic indicator/commodity, right?  There are hundreds (if not thousands) of economic indicators/commodities that are being tracked and reported.

I have a dataset of our daily sales volumes for the last 10 years.  I also have datasets of the daily prices of commodities (Oil, Fuel, Gold, Metals, etc.)

What analysis and tests do I perform to show a relationship between Crude Oil and our sales volume, or show that there is (likely) no relationship with Soybeans or Hog Futures!

The basic intent would be to then monitor those commodity forecasts to do early warning on our business activities.  The next level of maturity would be to then predict our performance-based the economic forecasts.

Comment: The simplest place to start is [ordinary least squares regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) and trying to estimate some linear function for expected sales conditional on various right hand side variables. Be aware that doing an excellent job with sensible standard errors will be tricky. There are numerous statistical issues such as: (i) are your processes [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)? (ii) Your residuals may be [autocorrelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)? etc...

Comment: You may want to find someone with a background in linear regression and time series analysis or perhaps develop your own knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To check for correlation, you can do the following:
1) Calculate [Pearson's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) $\hat\rho$ for the sales volume and any commodity. If you think that the commodity prices don't have an immediate effect on the sales, work with lagged values
(i.e. check the correlation between the sales volume $V_p,\dots,V_n$ and the commodity prices $p$ days ago, $C_1,\dots,C_{n-p}$).

2) Next, you should test whether the correlation is significantly different from zero. The correlation coefficient is approximately following a gaussian distribution for large sample sizes: $\mathcal{N}(\rho,1/\sqrt N)$, with $\rho$ being the real correlation and $N$ again denoting the sample size that is used in the correlation coefficient (if you test lagged values, use $N=n-p$).
You can thus construct a two-tailed hypothesis test with null hypothesis $\mathcal H_0: \rho=0$, alternative $\rho\ne0$ and test statistic $\hat\rho$.
The null hypothesis can be rejected at significance level $\alpha$, if
$$|\hat\rho|>\frac{q_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt N},$$
where $q$ denotes the respective gaussian quantile. For example, considering a significance level $\alpha=5\%$, we have $q_{0.975}\approx 1.96$.

3) If the null hypothesis above can be rejected, simply check whether $\hat\rho$ is positive or negative. A negative coefficient would confirm your suspicion that lower commodity prices imply higher sales volume.

With this knowledge, you could then proceed to forecast volume sales, incorporating commodity prices in an appropriate modelling framework.